# Programmatically starting Intellij remote debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is there a way to Programmatically start a Intellij remote debugger. I am looking for this beacuse I need to start a Java process (could be any jvm based program) in a seperate jvm but also want to seamlessly enable debugging within the IDE.

The process will be started from java file which will be in the IDE. I need to launch it in seperate JVM as its a loader program which would run outside the IDE. But when I work on it, I want to launch it same way it would start but be able to debug.

Comment: What kind of process you are running outside IntelliJ? Is it a build script? Maven? Gradle? Are you running it on the same machine or remotely?

Comment: Its a java program (production app) and will run on same machine. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IntelliJ "Remote" Run/Debug configuration.  Start your target process with "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" (for JVM 1.5 or later) then when  you run that config in IntelliJ it will attach to your remote process.